# Spring boot debug, warn and error logging stopped working

Tags: spring-boot, logging, slf4j

I have what may be a complex logging setup in my POM requiring some exclusions in order to work. The logging for debug, error and warning was working however I'm not certain exactly what is causing those to no longer log, with only info level logs logging.

Perhaps there is an easy solution but I'm imagining not as I wasn't after repeated attempts able to exclude any differently in order to have the logging work.

Here is the pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.jahtoe.tech</groupId>
    <artifactId>KeepaFBTDownloader</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>KeepaFBTDownloader</name>
    <description>Project for Keepa FBT Downloader</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-dependency-plugin.version>2.10</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Keepa</id>
            <name>Keepa Repository</name>
            <url>https://keepa.com/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev120-1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-java6</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev48-1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.54</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myjeeva.digitalocean</groupId>
            <artifactId>digitalocean-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.keepa.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdeferred</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdeferred-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Properties

```
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.com.mydomain=DEBUG
#logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
#logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.pattern.console= "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n"
logging.pattern.file= "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
logging.path=/home/vmdovs/logs/
```

Thanks
Conteh

Comment: With this information, I don't see anything that will stop logging for `WARN` or `ERROR` levels. Do check if you have any other logging configuration files(`logback.xml` etc) on your classpath.

Comment: @sukhpal-singh I don't have a logback.xml file in my project